# How to Hide Custom Tab View when I navigate from Main View to Detail View? | SwiftUI Code

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13, tabbar, swiftui-navigationlink

I have created a Custom Tab Bar & I want to Hide this Tab Bar when I navigate from Main View to Detail View.

> Tab Bar is appearing on both Main View & Detail View
>
> ContentView() to DetailView()
>
> Want to Hide Tab Bar in Detail View

Comment: Would you show your code?

Comment: Yes Sure, I will share